# use different mongos to drop and reCreate one database in mongodb cluster

Tags: mongodb

my cluster：2shard 3configSvr 3mongos
my mongo version: 3.2.10
problem:
If I have a database and I want to drop and reCreate it use different mongos. I will meet this problem.
database named exp:'mydb'
I use mongos1 to exec dropDatabase to drop database 'mydb'.
when it was droped. I use other mongos exp mongos2 to insert a data to database 'mydb'. It was successed in mongos2, and I can select this data in mongos3.
but I can't select this data in mongos1! In all 3configSvr have not 'mydb'.
If now I use mongos1 insert a data to 'mydb', all server will recovery. And configSvr will know 'mydb' was created now.

I try this way again. I must meet this problem.
If I use same mongos to drop and reCreate 'mydb'. It's no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem at https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-15213
It's a bug in mongodb and not fixed.
Now can use 'db.runCommand({"flushRouterConfig":1})' on all mongos when a databases was droped.